# change the color for item-icon in sidemenu in ionic when it is activated

Tags: ionic-framework

In the Ionic app, I need to change the background color for my side menu to become red . By default , when I click or press on one item stable color become the background color but I need to become red  .

see this 
[image]

Comment: did your issue resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sass](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html) to build your own custumized ionic.css

Comment: i know that the sass is used but i don't know the classes i need to overwrite !

Answer (score 0):

You can give custom css to set the background color like `<ion-content class="dark">`

Css

```
.dark {
  background-color: red !important;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Sample HTML

```
<ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Left Menu</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content class="dark">
          <ion-list class="list">
            <ion-item href="#/event/check-in">Check-in</ion-item>
            <ion-item href="#/event/attendees">Attendees</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
```

You can check the full code/demo on the codpen which have proper comments also : http://codepen.io/mhartington/pen/qafgv

For the other reference you can check this also : http://pointdeveloper.com/ionic-change-side-menu-color/

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding `item.active.item-stable` and `item.activated.item-stable` styles in your custom CSS.

Add below styles in your custom CSS:

```
.item.active.item-stable, .item.activated.item-stable, .item-complex.active .item-content.item-stable, .item-complex.activated .item-content.item-stable, .item .item-content.active.item-stable, .item .item-content.activated.item-stable{
    border-color: #B81D22;
    background-color: #B81D22;
}
```